# ssl certificate failure for bundle install

Tags: ruby, ssl, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I have a ruby application, that needs gems from my proprietary source location. When I try to run bundle install it gives an error

> There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
>   information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.

When I try to install the same gem and version using gem intall on command line, it succeeds. The certificates for the site are configured in `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`

After this I did following each completing without error

```
gem install openssl
rvm get head
rvm pkg remove
rvm requirements run
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
cd ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ssl_certs/
```

Copied the certificates for the site from `/etc/ssl/certs/`.

`bundle install` fails with the above error, specifying the gem actually failing. If I do `gem install` for the errored gem, it succeeds.

It seems the bundler cant find the certificates required. Any ideas where they should be going other than the paths mentioned above?

I am using ubuntu 10.04.4 lucid for development.

Answer (score 0):

After exhaustive search, the problem was in the certificates, the certification authority was changed recently and required the CA certificates to be downloaded from the providers website.